# C#: Remove Excess Text From String

Tags: c#, string

Okay, so after looking around here on SO, I have found a solution that meets about 95% of my requirement, although I believe it may need to be redone at this point.

***ISSUE***

Say I have a value range supplied as "1000 - 1009 ABC1 ABC SOMETHING ELSE" where I just need the 1000 - 1009 part. I need to be able to remove excess characters from the string supplied, even if they truly are accepted characters, but only if they are part of secondary strings with text. (Sorry if that description seems odd, my mind isn't full power today.)

***CURRENT SOLUTION***

I currently have a simple method utilizing Linq to return only accepted characters, however this will return "1000 - 10091" which is not the range I am needing. I've thought about looping through the strings individual characters and comparing to previous characters as I go using `IsDigit` and `IsLetter` to my advantage, but then comes the issue of replacing the unacceptable characters or removing them. I think if I gave it a day or two I could figure it out with a clear mind, but it needs to be done by the end of the day, and I am banging my head against the keyboard.

```
void RemoveExcessText(ref string val) {
    string allowedChars = "0123456789-+>";
    val = new string(val.Where(c => allowedChars.Contains(c)).ToArray());
}


// Alternatively?
char previousChar = ' ';
for (int i = 0; i < val.Length; i++) {
    if (char.IsLetter(val[i])) {
        previousChar = val[i];
        val.Remove(i, 1);
    } else if (char.IsDigit(val[i])) {
        if (char.IsLetter(previousChar)) {
            val.Remove(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

But how do I calculate white space and leave in the +, -, and > charactrers? I am losing my mind on this one today.

Comment: Do you want to keep all the characters *until* you encounter the first illegal character?

Comment: Will the string you need to keep always be the same length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use a regular expression?

```
Regex.Match("1000 - 1009 ABC1 ABC SOMETHING ELSE", @"^(\d+)([\s\-]+)(\d+)");
```

Should give you what you want

[I made a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3mkC9p)

Comment: This tells him whether the string looks like his requirement, but it doesn't give him the contents..

Comment: @CaiusJard not true, check the fiddle (you're probably thinking `Regex.IsMatch`, not `Regex.Match`)

Comment: My bad; I read it as `Regex.IsMatch` - i tend to forget about Match as being a shortcut for Matches[0]

Comment: This solution does not account for potentially missing or extra spaces between the digits and the dash.

Comment: @Juan although not requested in the question, I've updated to allow any combination of whitespace or dash in between the two numbers

Comment: Thank you, the pattern I used was: " *\d+ *- *\d+ *"

Comment: @lxxtacoxxl: That pattern may match other things. I would recommend targeting meaningless white space specifically.

Comment: @lxxtacoxxl I used capturing groups (parenthesis) since you may want to use that regex to capture the min/max values, but it makes no sense on `Regex.Matches` so you may want to leave those out (as you did). I'd still match whitespace specifically (with `\s`, instead of spaces)

Comment: Also, using * on the digits is not a great idea (you want at least one digit, not zero... that'd mean that's not a range). If you want to simplify it and allow for any amount of whitespace (or none) and one dash in between, try `^\d+\s*-\s*\d+`. Check it out: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0fHBvW

Comment: @Jcl if you notice in the pattern I use the one or more notation '+' for my digits and the zero or more notation '*' for my whitespace as it's possible to be there but is not a requirement. Thank you for making those points however, as they may be useful in my future with `Regex`.

Answer (score 1):

You use a regular expression with a capturing group:

```
Regex r = new Regex("^(?<v>[-0-9 ]+?)");
```

This means "from the start of the input string (^) match [0 to 9 or space or hyphen] and keep going for as many occurrences of these characters as are available (+?) and store it into variable v (?)"

We get it out like this:

```
r.Matches(input)[0].Groups["v"].Value
```

Note though that if the input string doesn't match, the match collection will be 0 long and a call to [0] will crash. To this end you might want to robust it up with some extra error checking:

```
MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(input);
if(mc.Length > 0)
  MessageBox.Show(mc[0].Groups["v"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could match this with a regular expression.  \d{1,4} means match a decimal digit at least once up to 4 times.  Followed by space, hyphen, space, and 1 to 4 digits again, then anything else.  Only the part inside parenthesis is output in your results.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var pattern = @"(^\d{1,4} - \d{1,4}).*";
        string input = ("1000 - 1009 ABC1 ABC SOMETHING ELSE");
        string replacement = "$1";
        string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/cZGlX4